# Reassembly fails at destination

Tags: linux, linux-networking, udp, mtu, ip-fragmentation

Say I have Host1 & 2 connected to a router with different speeds.

```
Host1  <--100 Mbps-->  Router  <--10 Mbps-->  Host2
```

Host1 sends 10MB of UDP data using **nc** command to Host2, but the Host2 fails in reassembling fragmented packets and sends ICMP(Time-to-live exceeded/Fragment reassembly time excedded).

When the both ends are 100 Mbps, I don't see any failure and no fragmentation happens.

I tried to avoid fragmentation by following methods

```
1. Enabling PMTU on destination, router 
        echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_no_pmtu_disc
2. Reducing MTU to 576 from 1500
```

But still fragmentation happens. I can see through wireshark log. Can you please guide me to avoid fragmentation and how to handle this scenario.

**Edit:** 
This is kind of stress scenario from router perspective. I should not change anything on source/destination side.

Answer (score 2):

The key issue here is not fragmentation, it is packet loss that happens on a router when its queue fills up. Then some fragments are dropped and you see a reassembly failure.

To avoid fragmentation you should set your packet size on a sending side so that fragmentation would not happen, but even if you'd do so you're likely to see a packet loss in this same scenario because of the speed difference and router's buffer size limits.

You can use `socat` that allows you to set your packet size with UDP (a feature that `netcat` does not seem to have, as it just dumps whatever data it has in the buffer into a single packet) and set it so that fragmentation won't happen and observe the results predicted above.

In general the above is a nature of pure UDP that one can only avoid by implementing certain flow-control protocol on top of UDP.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't see any information about packets drops in `/proc/net/snmp` or `/proc/net/udp` of router. Any other place I should be looking for packet drops? At the moment I'm interested in log about packet drops in /var/log at least.

Comment: Sending side I see offset 0 on all packets in wireshark. i.e sender  side there is no fragmentation. only router does fragmentation.